# list files in folder and subfolders and output the result in multiple files for each parent folder

Tags: csv, vbscript

I am using the code for listing files in a folder.

```
Dim fso
Dim ObjOutFile

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ObjOutFile = fso.CreateTextFile(GetFiles(FolderName) & "_"&"OutputFiles.csv")

ObjOutFile.WriteLine("Type,File Name,File Path")
GetFiles("YOUR LOCATION")
ObjOutFile.Close

WScript.Echo("Completed")

Function GetFiles(FolderName)
    On Error Resume Next

    Dim ObjFolder
    Dim ObjSubFolders
    Dim ObjSubFolder
    Dim ObjFiles
    Dim ObjFile

    Set ObjFolder = fso.GetFolder(FolderName)
    Set ObjFiles = ObjFolder.Files

    For Each ObjFile In ObjFiles
        ObjOutFile.WriteLine("File," & ObjFile.Name & "," & ObjFile.Path)
    Next

    Set ObjSubFolders = ObjFolder.SubFolders

    For Each ObjFolder In ObjSubFolders
        ObjOutFile.WriteLine("Folder," & ObjFolder.Name & "," & ObjFolder.Path)
        GetFiles(ObjFolder.Path)
    Next
End Function
```

I am getting Output as _OutputFiles.csv

If I run the script in a folder I want the output as

```
New Folder (3)_OutputFiles.csv
New Folder (2)_OutputFiles.csv
```

with all files listed.

Please suggest how to implement such that I get output for each parent folder separately.

Comment: SO is not a code (re-)writing service. What have you tried so far, and what particular problem do you need help with?

Comment: @Ansgar Wiechers - I want to get multiple outputs for each parent folder. I don't know where to put this condition in the above code.
For Each ObjFolder in (MyLocation)
ObjOutFile = fso.CreateTextFile(ObjFolder.Name & "_"&"OutputFiles.csv")

Comment: Around the code that handles the output file, obviously.

Comment: 'Set ObjOutFile = fso.CreateTextFile(GetFiles(FolderName) & "_"&"OutputFiles.csv")'

I added this line but it is running as _output.csv.

Comment: Update your question with the full non-working code you currently have as well as a concise problem description. I'm not going to guess what the problem might be from bits and pieces you drop in comments.

Comment: @Ansgar Wiechers - I have updated the question. please help me out with this.

Thanks

Comment: Your function doesn't return anything (effectively making it a sub rather than a function), so how do you expect something like `GetFiles(FolderName) & "_OutputFiles.csv"` to work? Particularly if you want just the value of `FolderName` in the filename. Also, your code doesn't populate `FolderName` in the first place. You need the loop from your first comment to do that.

Comment: @Ansgar Wiechers - I don't want the folder name but file names inside the folders in the outputfile, but separate output files for each parent folder. **Please help me, i am a beginner in programming.**
Thanks

Comment: Please find a tutorial on VBScript and learn the language first. Without that any answer would boil down to writing the script for you. Which is not what SO is for.

Answer (score 0):

You have to move your definition of the output file AFTER you obtain the parent folder name, and include the .Name attribute of the folder.

```
Dim fso
Dim ObjOutFile

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
GetFiles("YOUR LOCATION")
ObjOutFile.Close

WScript.Echo("Completed")

Function GetFiles(FolderName)
    On Error Resume Next

    Dim ObjFolder
    Dim ObjSubFolders
    Dim ObjSubFolder
    Dim ObjFiles
    Dim ObjFile

    Set ObjFolder = fso.GetFolder(FolderName)
        Set ObjOutFile = fso.CreateTextFile(GetFiles(FolderName.Name) & "_"&"OutputFiles.csv")  
        ObjOutFile.WriteLine("Type,File Name,File Path")
    Set ObjFiles = ObjFolder.Files

    For Each ObjFile In ObjFiles
        ObjOutFile.WriteLine("File," & ObjFile.Name & "," & ObjFile.Path)
    Next

    Set ObjSubFolders = ObjFolder.SubFolders

    For Each ObjFolder In ObjSubFolders
        ObjOutFile.WriteLine("Folder," & ObjFolder.Name & "," & ObjFolder.Path)
        GetFiles(ObjFolder.Path)
    Next
End Function
```